# While intsalling cakephp on ububtu 11.10 give rewrite_module error

Tags: php, apache, cakephp-1.3

I am attempting to install cakephp-1.3 on Ubuntu 11.10. I have finished all the required changes in the configuration file as mention in http://book.cakephp.org.

- It shows all database connections as being setup.
- Temp folder is rewrite-able.

But it give me an apache module rewrite error. I have checked the apache rewrite mode and it is enabled.

But I still get the `URL_REWRITE` error repeatedly and am unsure how to proceed. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if mod_rewrite is actually on. To do that, make a php file with

```
<?php php_info(); ?>
```

in your web root folder. At Loaded Modules you should see mod_rewrite.

If not, check for the line:

```
 LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

In httpd.conf (apache2.conf in UBUNTU > /etc/apache2/apache2.conf). It must be uncomented (without ; in front).

Check if AllowOverride option is on for your project. To do that, add the following line at the end of httpd.conf (apache2.conf in UBUNTU)

```
<Directory "/var/www/myProjectName">
 AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for help... I checked apache.conf file. LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so is unable over there....